# How to Use Child Routing to Populate the Parent's RouterOutlet in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

The home page of my app is just

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

and the class looks something like this:

```
@RouteConfig([
    {path:'/', name: 'StartScreen', component: StartScreen, useAsDefault: true}
])

export class AppHome {
    constructor(private router: Router) {}
}
```

Which gets populated by a default route for the start screen, which contains a search box. This part worked until I wanted to do more...

By clicking search, it triggers this function in the start screen class:

```
@RouteConfig([
    {path:'/...', name: 'Results', component: Results}
])


export class StartScreen{
    private router : Router

    constructor(router: Router)
        this.router = router;
    }

    search(input) {
        this.data.search(input);
        this.router.parent.navigate(['Results']);
    }
}
```

The start screen does not have it's own RouterOutlet. I actually want the "Results" template to replace the start screen and populate the home page's RouterOutlet.

Am I on the right track and my problems are due to other syntax errors, or I'm going about it incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try child routes.

Eg. in your `AppHome` component, change `@RouteConfig` to something like

```
@RouteConfig([
    {path:'/startscreen/...', name: 'StartScreen', component: StartScreen, useAsDefault: true}
])
```

And, in the `StartScreen` component, define `@RouteConfig` like

```
@RouteConfig([
    {path:'/result1', name: 'Result1', component: Result1},
    {path:'/result2', name: 'Result2', component: Result2},
    //and something like that
])
```

Also refer to

[How to use child routes in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36927731/how-to-use-child-routing-to-populate-the-parents-routeroutlet-in-angular-2)

Comment: The link redirects to this page btw. All the examples I've seen always have the parent component populating itself with a component that goes on to populating itself. Will this allow for the child component to populate the parent?

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was...

At the `AppHome` level, there are two views that can populate `RouterOutlet`:

```
@RouteConfig([
  {path:'/', name: 'StartScreen', component: StartScreen, useAsDefault: true},
  {path:'/Results/...', name: 'Results', component: Results}
])
```

When a search is triggered in the `StartScreen` DOM, it triggers the search function above, that routes to `Results`, which has its own set of routes:

```
 search(input) {
    this.data.search(input);
    this.router.parent.navigate(['Results']);
 }
```